# How to display enter key in iOS keypad for textView (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, iphone-keypad

I want to display enter key on keyboard instead of return key. Because i want user to type in a texView. We know that there is no keypad return in textView. Generally, i want to replace the "return" key with "enter". Normally in textView, the return key works as enter. So i need the return key labeled as enter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **returnKeyType** attribute:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyTypeDone
```

Here are the available options:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIReturnKeyType) {
    UIReturnKeyDefault,
    UIReturnKeyGo,
    UIReturnKeyGoogle,
    UIReturnKeyJoin,
    UIReturnKeyNext,
    UIReturnKeyRoute,
    UIReturnKeySearch,
    UIReturnKeySend,
    UIReturnKeyYahoo,
    UIReturnKeyDone,
    UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
    UIReturnKeyContinue NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0),
};
```

Comment: then can i add an extra attribute as UIReturnKeyEnter?

Comment: @soorejbabu if you see the word ENUM in a property, it means you're restricted in choices. Hence, you can only use one from the list above. I would therefore maybe use 'UIReturnKeyDone', as that's the closest one.

Comment: oh... ok ok. i got it. i used the UIReturnKeyDefault.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set Enter But You can set a numbers of default key for keyboard instead of return from storyboard.In you scenario Done will be nice.

[image: see in image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set custom text for the return key on iOS. There are a number of [options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType) but those are the only ones.